# FTPed to server running sentora and only found empty / folder

Tags: ftp

I just FTPed to my server with a fresh Sendora install. All i can see is / folder. The / folder is completely empty.

Instruction on my website, when visiting, mydomain.com, say that I should: Replace or delete this file (index.html).

But then again, I have no index.html file. All I see is / folder. What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. When creating ftp user's home directory, I needed to check Use Domain directory option.